# Чтение файла построчно в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, python-2.x

Здраствуйте. В txt файле записано:

```
97
115
116
```

Каждое число записано с новой строки. Хотелось создать переменную или массив содержащий число, но банальный `a = f.read()` не помогает, так как считывает целеком весь файл. Помогите пожалуйста)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Видимо вы поленились почитать про чтение файлов в python, поскольку сразу за `file.read()` обычно в учебниках рассказывается о `file.readline()` и `file.readlines()`
Поэтому у вас 3 варианта:

1. Читать в цикле файл построчно через `file.readline()`
2. Читать весь файл сразу в список через `file.readlines()`, но тогда вам самостоятельно придется избавляться от символов перевода строки
3. Читать файл за один раз целиком и обрабатывать его через `splitlines()` - `file.read().splitlines()` - тоже сразу в список и без символов перевода строк.

Последний вариант самый привлекательный, на мой взгляд:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    nums = f.read().splitlines()
print(nums)
```

> ['97', '115', '116']

Comment: в тексте помарка, 3-й пункт - splitlibes() (b - libes). Редактор не хочет принимать правку одной буквы. Исправьте сами)))

Answer (score 5):

test.txt

```
97
115
116
```

---

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    myList = [ line.split() for line in f ]

print(myList)
[['97'], ['115'], ['116']]

flatList = [item for sublist in myList for item in sublist]
print(flatList)
['97', '115', '116']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
    str = [row.strip() for row in file]
```